# was item() one of the array object methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

i was reading 'javascript and jquery interactive front-end web development' book , and encountered this sentence

> you can see an array created using a different technique called an
> array constructor. This uses the new keyword followed by Array(); The
> values are then specified in parentheses (not square brackets), and
> each value is separated by a comma. You can also use a method called i
> tern() to retrieve data from the array.

```
var colors = new Array('white ' ,
'black',
'custom');
var el = document.getElementByid( ' colors' );
el.innerHTML = colors.item(O);
```

i tried to apply that , and got prompted with an error

> Uncaught TypeError: colors.item is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was item() one of the array object methods

No, `item` is a method on various collection interfaces used with JavaScript (like DOM collections, [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) and such), but not an array method. It may also have been added to `Array.prototype` by some libraries before extending built-ins was largely determined to be a bad idea for libraries.

However, there's a Stage 3 proposal for adding a similar method [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method), although with a different name (`at` rather than `item`; originally it was going to be `item` but it turned out that was incompatible with too much code on the web).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the question, but if you ever wonder how to write it properly :

```js
const colors = ['white', 'black', 'custom'];
const el = document.getElementByid('colors');
el.innerHTML = colors[0];
```